# gwt beginner- how to show an image as part of a gwt module

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I am trying to display an image using GWT Graphics library--

In this the javadoc says--

```
 Image(int x, int y, int width, int height, String href)

 The URI of the raster image to be displayed is specified as a string.
```

Now, how do I specify the URI of the image? What is the generic method of specifying the URI for an image in GWT? And where do I store the image? Within "war" or "war/web-inf/" or some other location?

Answer (score 1):

You can select an arbitrary directory for saving images; I ususally use war/images. The Images can then be displayed using new Image("images/myimage.png") in a panel.

Comment: Did this solve your question? If yes, would you be so kind to mark this answer as solution? Thanks!